# Adding a key/value to an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to know if there is a way by which I can add a key/value pair to an already existing dictionary which has 3 key value/pairs already. I want to add the new key/pair under the the 3rd object i.e.

```
[0]test - 1 key/value pair
[1]test1 - 1 key/value pair
[2]test3 - 1 key/value pair
```

I need to search for test3 than add an key value pair under it

Comment: Can you add more code on what you have tried? And what the error is?

Answer (score 1):

1. if you need to 'edit' a dictionary. you need to make it mutable. - NSMutableDictionay

   NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = **your_dict**.mutableCopy;
   mutableDict[**new_key**] = **new_value**;
   **your_dict_** = mutableDict.copy;

of course, you can choose to use NSMutableDictionary at the beginning.

2. Dictionary DOES NOT save order. It will only 'order' itself by sorting its keys. To do it in a proper way, you should use an array to store the keys' orders.

so for your case, assuming you will update them frequently:

```
NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dicts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[keys insertObject:__new_key__ atIndex:[keys indexOfObject:__new_key] + 1]];
dicts[__new_key__] = __new_value;
```

Answer (score -4):

Its very easy in swift. you can create variable dictionary and add key value by direct assigning. if that key already exists it will replace it with new value. Example

var dict1 = String    : AnyObject

```
    dict1["Test"] = 1
    dict1["Test2"] = 23
    dict1["Test3"] = "4"
    dict1["Test"] = "4"
```

Now here test key already exists so it will replace its value from 1 to 4.

Comment: question is about ObjC